# Simple Streamlabs OBS text Fade in and out. Fade in wouldn't work

Tags: html, css

This are the codes that I am using for the CSS and HTML

```css
#alert-text {
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    animation: fadein 3s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s 11s forwards;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000, 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 3px #000, 0px 0px 4px #000, 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="alert-text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#alert-text {
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    animation: fade 12s forwards;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000, 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 3px #000, 0px 0px 4px #000, 0px 0px 5px #000;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    12% {
        /*12/100 */
        opacity: 1;
    }

    88% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="alert-text">Alert!</p>
```

You need to add Keyframes

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: even if I don't add keyframes, the fade-in still doesn't work only fade out

Comment: Hi, thanks it works. how can I make the text pop up at 100 opacity when it's at 2 seconds? cause I tried to mingle the commands a bit it's starting from 10 then slowly going to 100 opacity

Comment: nvm I got hehehe THANKS A LOT